# NServiceBus is blocking when hosted in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, nservicebus

I created a simple web application where a search form is filled out, submit
button clicked, and a message is sent with the search parameters via
nServiceBus. I also have a handler in the same project that picks up the message
(from the same queue). For some reason, the web server process blocks until
after the message is picked up, is there any reason for this? I set a breakpoint
in the message handler and it breaks before the request finishes... locking the
browser until I allow the code to continue. I would expect control to return to
the browser regardless of when the handler gets fired...

Thanks,
D.Niemeyer

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .RegisterWebCallback() in your code, as that is what is responsible for preventing ASP.NET to complete the HTTP call?

Comment: Hi Udi,
No I am not calling RegisterWebCallback() anywhere, just IBus.Send, with a message handler, in an MVC application. Send looks like this:

bus.Send<SearchMessage>(m => m.Message = "test");

Handler looks like this (as simple as I could make this test):

public class SearchMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<SearchMessage>
{
 public void Handle(SearchMessage message)
 {
  string s = message.Message;
 }
}

Comment: I'm also seeing this, even in release mode deployed to a web server.  I'm using MVC as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the nServiceBus forum. This is a phenomenon caused by having the debugger attached, which stops all threads if a breakpoint is hit before the response is returned. Placing a sleep in the handler demonstrates this.